# Angular2: unable to return a json mapped from an Http response

Tags: javascript, json, angular, observable

In my service I execute an http call and return the response as `Observable`

```
doQuery ( query: String ) : Observable<any> {
    return this.http.request(queryURL) ;   
}
```

And in a component I subscribe

```
this.service
    .doQuery(this.query)
    .subscribe((res: any) => {
        console.log ("Res");
        console.log(res);
    });
```

Doing this actually works; I can see in the console the dump of a `Response` object

My problem came when I want to return from the service the response alread mapped as json.

I trying to do tyhis

```
return this.http.request(queryURL).map((res: any) => res.json());
```

But at runtime I got an obscure javascript error (this is coming from Zone.js to be precise)

```
Error: Permission denied to access property "rejection"
```

I've already tried to change the return type from `Observable<any>` to `Observable<any[]>`, as seen on a book, but without success.

**UPDATE** : 
Actually I resolved adding into the service file this

`import 'rxjs/Rx';`

**What am I doing wrong? Why is this import needed ? Isn't a way to import Rxjs' map operator?**

Comment: If you found an answer to your question, please add your own reply with the solution for other people to find.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this specific situation, i resolved adding the import

```
import `rxjs/Rx`;
```

But in the 99% of other times this happened again to me, this error was due to a missing declaration of one service in the `providers` array in the @NgModule